# Powershell - (Active Directory Module) - Get-ADGroupMember only works for groups in my Domain

Tags: powershell, active-directory, active-directory-group

I'm a bit embarrassed to say how much time I've spent on this!

I dont have any issues using the ADUC GUI (Active Directory User and Computers) to find the group, *All Supervisors* in *east.ad.company.com*.  The result comes up within a few seconds.

However, if I try to do the same thing using the Active Directory module:

***Get-ADGroupMember "All Supervisors" -server east.ad.company.com***

produces the error:

*....FullyQualifiedErrorId : Cannot find an object with identity: 'All Supervisors' under: 'DC=east,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember...*

**---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

A few things to note:

- Group scope of *"All Supervisors"* is Universal (not sure if that makes
  a difference)
- My Computer and AD user account is currently in the
  *west.ad.company.com*
- I can successfully use Get-AdGroupMember as long as it's in the same
  domain as me
- I can successfully use *get-aduser -identity ADUserID -server
  ba.ad.ssa.gov*

**---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**Lastly:**
I would also like to know how to do the equivalent of searching in ADUC for Users and Groups in "Entire Directory" in Powershell (ideally a simple function or script I can use to quickly search do this at the command-line; instead of depending on the ADUC GUI app).  Surely, there has to be a way to do this using pure powershell!

Answer (score 2):

Searching the 'Entire Directory' is known as a Global Catalog search, so you just need to tell PowerShell to use the Global Catalog.  It's found on DCs on port 3268 (instead of 389).  Not all domain controllers have to hold the Global Catalog - it's up to your admins to decide.  You can query for GC servers with

```
(Get-ADForest).GlobalCatalogs
```

I only have a single domain, so i can't test this but I believe you'll want something like:

```
Get-ADGroupMember "All Supervisors" -server dc1.east.ad.company.com:3268 -SearchBase ad.company.com
```

assuming your forest root is ad.company.com.

Comment: -searchbase is not a valid parameter for Get-AdGroupMember:  SYNTAX
    Get-ADGroupMember [-Identity] <ADGroup> [-AuthType {Negotiate | Basic}] [-Credential
    <PSCredential>] [-Partition <string>] [-Recursive <switch>] [-Server <string>] [<CommonParameters>]

Comment: All our GC's have DNS names identifying them.  I did try just using everything except the -Searchbase parameter; however, the group still couldn't be found.  One interesting thing to note, I dont have any issues with searching the builtin AD groups such as "Domain Admins" in other domains.

Comment: ***SearchBase***  not parameter for **Get--ADGroupMember** ? For me, wrong

Answer (score 2):

`Get-ADObject` has the `-SearchBase parameter` you're looking for.  Pipe the result (group object) to `Get-ADGroupMember` to list the members.  Oh and `'name -eq "foo"'` can and probably should be tweaked to be a unique property, otherwise  you could get any number of groups' memberships listed.

```
Get-ADObject -Filter { 'ObjectClass -eq "group"' -and 'name -eq "All Supervisors"' } -SearchBase 'DC=east,DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com' | Get-ADGroupMember
```

Comment: I get error ***Get-ADObject : Error parsing query: ' 'ObjectClass -eq "group"' -and 'name -eq "ROLE_A"' ' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '2'.***

Comment: I got errors too.  Looks like Get-ADGroupMember acts poorly when piped groups from different domains.  At least I can't get it to act correctly.

Get-ADGroup works cleanly and simply, and the .Members property can be expanded to get a list of DistinguishedNames of the group members, to use in whatever.  See new answer I added.

Answer (score 2):

Edit:
The previous answer did not work.  Using Get-ADObject with Get-ADGroupMembers was throwing errors related to the admin console being in a different domain.

I explored the properties of the ADGroup object and found the .members property.  The following snippet will list the DistingushedName of the members of the "All Supervisors" group in domain "east.ad.company.com".  If you are running from the domain you can most likely leave off -server "east.ad.company.com".

So Try:

```
 Get-ADGroup "All Supervisors" -Server east.ad.company.com -Property Members | Select -ExpandProperty Members
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)

Comment: Ok, I edited it.  My previous answer was not working due to Get-ADGroupMembers not liking to look in different domain for the group.

Answer (score 1):

Found that you can list Universal group members with `get-adgroupmember` across domains.
Simply pass the name of the other domain at the `-server` name.

```
get-adgroupmember RTCUniversalServerAdmins -server the.other.dom | ft -a -prop name,samAccountName
```